# Load Wordpress page content from external php

Tags: php, wordpress

Has anyone ever used wordpress as a CMS and tried to render pages, articles and widgets on php-pages which are on the same server, but in another directory? I have to mix two CMSs as a migration strategy to wordpress.

Lets say wordpress is installed in folder ./wp and there is a page with permalink /wp/testpage. I create a file test.php in folder ./tests/
What I alreay tried is:

```
<?php 
  global $page; 
  $page = 616; //looked up post id

 require_once '../wp/index.php';

?>
```

But that just shows me a 404 wordpress page - footer and header are loaded correctly, but not the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to require the wp-load.php file from the blog you need. Then you can get the content from the blog using the wordpress functions.

```
<?php
require_once("../wp/wp-load.php");
$my_postid = 616;
$content_post = get_post($my_postid);
$content = $content_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);

echo $content;
```

<strike>not tested but I have it similar to this somewhere in my php files.</strike>
edit: just tested. Works as expected.

Comment: it's also worth setting `define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);` before you include the WP code, so it doesn't try render anything to the screen.

Comment: @MatthewKnight not needed as with the above code you get the content only without any theme.

Comment: Content is returned, works fine.
Is there also a way to return the whole article with headline and image and optionally also with  header and footer?

Comment: @mc77de you could just grab one of your existing templates from the wordpress installation - that should have all of the layout code, all of the fields you want displaying. add the `wp-load.php` file at the top. you might need to fix some filepaths, but it should work with a little tweaking.